# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ObjectId" with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have need to use mongoose find method with "_id" instead of findById.

In my router I receive a correct string "_id" from my front end app:

```
req.query.where="591f47d10d957323386f0c42".
```

With robomongo, the next  works well:

```
db.getCollection('ag_escalaatendimentos').find({'_id':ObjectId('59247524723dec26aca239ed')})
```

But when I run the app I get an error:

My error is:

```
"ObjectId" message:"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ObjectId {↵  path: '591f47d10d957323386f0c42',↵  instance: 'ObjectID',↵  validators: [],↵  setters: [],↵  getters: [],↵  options: undefined,↵  _index: null }" at path "_id" for model "Ag_escalaatendimento""
name:
"CastError" path:"_id" stringValue: ""ObjectId {path: '591f47d10d957323386f0c42',  instance: 'ObjectID',  validators: [],  setters: [],  getters: [],  options: undefined,↵  _index: null }""
```

//code

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Ag_escalaatendimento = require('../models/ag_escalaatendimento');

const callback=function(err,data,res){
         //if (err) console.log(err);
         if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
         return res.status(200).send(data);
    }   



//get all

router.get('/',function(req,res,next){  
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

        //Here I have req.query.where: "591f47d10d957323386f0c42".
        var qrySearch={"_id": new ObjectId(req.query.where)};
            Ag_escalaatendimento.find(qrySearch)
            .exec( (err,data) => {
               callback(err,data,res)
            })
        });
```

Comment: `querySearch={ "_id": req.query.where }`. Mongoose will do it for you. That said, I see no reason why you cannot `.findById(req.query.where)`

Comment: @ Neil Lunn Your suggestion to querySearch return no documents. I already tried it. As you can see in my post, robomango return one document.

Comment: Show the document you think you should be retrieving. The text output and not a screenshot please. Also include your schema definition if you are possibly overriding the definition of `_id`. The general cause will be that the value is not in fact an `ObjectId` but a "string" in the database ( usually from bad code ). Or indeed that there is simply no document to match.

Comment: You might also want to define `mongoose.model("Ag_escalaatendimento", ag_escalaatendimentos")` to explicitly name the collection to be used in case this is a problem with how mongoose is interpreting what the collection name should be. And finally check you are actually connecting to the same database.

Comment: Thank you Mr Neil Lunn. I will see it now.

Comment: Mr Neil Lun, you are correct. I was searching the wrong id. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Neil mentioned in the comments, Mongoose will automatically convert strings to `ObjectId`s when appropriate. However, the root cause of your problem is that you're using the wrong `ObjectId` class. Mongoose actually provides two different classes with the same name:

- `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`
- `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

You should use the first one when defining schemas and the second one when explicitly creating `ObjectId`s for queries. Replacing the one line where you define `ObjectId` fixes your code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

//Here I have req.query.where: "591f47d10d957323386f0c42".
var qrySearch={"_id": new ObjectId(req.query.where)};
    Ag_escalaatendimento.find(qrySearch)
    .exec( (err,data) => {
       callback(err,data,res)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your tip.