# find by id and delete using mongoose mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to nodejs and mongodb, I am trying to delete a category from category document. Category document contains ObjectId of user document. When user adds a category, I save user's id in category document.

This is category document:

```
 {
    "isActive": true,
    "_id": "5bded03fe125544798039c2c",
    "name": "aaaaaaaa",
    "description": "test",
    "imageUrl": "test",
    "user": "5bdec5f94a9730439590a164",
    "__v": 0
}
```

User Schema:

```
 const UserSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    minlength:3
 },
email: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    minlength:5
},
 password: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
    minlength:6
 },
 isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
 },
 date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
 }
});
```

Category Schema:

```
const CategorySchema = new Schema({
user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
},
name: {
    type: String,
    required:true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
},
imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required:true,
},
isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
}
});
```

Following is my delete request code:

```
router.delete('/:cat_id', (req, res) => {
   Category.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.cat_id)
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Category deleted successfully!' 
   });
    }).catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
  });
```

When i hit delete request, it gives me following error:

```
{
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"5bded03fe125544798039c2cs\" at path \"_id\" for model \"categories\"",
"name": "CastError",
"stringValue": "\"5bded03fe125544798039c2cs\"",
"kind": "ObjectId",
"value": "5bded03fe125544798039c2cs",
"path": "_id"
}
```

I tried this solution also but didn't worked :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147638/10603547
It gave me following error

```
 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

What is wrong in my code? Thank you

Comment: `5bded03fe125544798039c2cs` is 25 characters long so not a valid objectID. Your category document JSON says `5bded03fe125544798039c2c` so some extra s is being appended somewhere

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. Simple mistake by me... thanks bro